# Unexpected output shape from a keras dense layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I try to create a minimal **non-convolutional** NN image binary classifier with one hidden layer only (as a practice before more complicated models):

```
def make_model(input_shape):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = layers.Dense(128, activation="ReLU")(inputs)
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model = make_model(input_shape=(256, 256, 3))
```

Its `model.summary()` shows

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 256, 256, 3)]     0                                                                       
 dense (Dense)               (None, 256, 256, 128)     512                                                                    
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 256, 256, 1)       129                                                      
=================================================================
Total params: 641
Trainable params: 641
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Since the `dense_1` layer has one neuron only, what I expect from this layer is an output shape of `(None, 1)` (i,e, a single number indicating the predicted binary label) but instead the model gives `(None, 256, 256, 1)`.

What's wrong with my model setting and how can I get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to flatten your preposterously large tensor if you want to use the output shape `(None, 1)`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def make_model(input_shape):
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model = make_model(input_shape=(256, 256, 3))
print(model.summary())
```

Comment: Hy @AloneTogether, thanks for the answer. Just tried, it works. But I am a bit confused about the necessity of the `flatten()` operation--suppose a layer has one node only, no matter how many nodes can send signals to this layer, this layer should only be able to output one scalar signal. So why is an explicit `flatten()` a must?

Comment: Your input data is 3D (excluding the batch size) and you want a 1D output (again excluding the batch size), that is why you need the `Flatten` layer. Oh, and by the way, a `Dense` layer is only applied to the last dimension of your tensor. That is for example why you get the output shape `(None, 256, 256, 128)` in your first `Dense` layer.

Comment: Thanks @AloneTogether, I have seem something similar to what you said in your comment on the Internet. I did not quite get their points so I skipped that. Guess I need to RTFM to get what exactly you are talking about. Thanks!

Comment: I understand your theoretical thinking, definitely, but this is how Keras works.

Comment: @AlexKong "So why is an explicit flatten() a must?" Because applying `Dense` to a non-flattened Conv2D layer is also useful, it works as a 1x1 convolution, which helps reduce the amount of parameters in your model. Also, applying `Dense` to a 2D tensor can be thought of as a simple MLP with a batch size. It is what it is - applying `Dense` to a tensor only performs the fully-connected operation on the last dimension.

Comment: I get a follow-up question which is a bit beyond my theoretical limit: the design of the current model is `Dense(128, activation="ReLU"); Flatten(); Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")`. Suppose I switch the order of these three layers, making them `Flatten(); Dense(128, activation="ReLU"); Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")`, (i.e., `flatten()` before the hidden layer), will the model be essentially the same? (In terms of both performance and computation needed). (I will try the switch myself after my poor GPU finish the current training, but not yet)

Comment: You will have way more trainable parameters with that suggestion (because as I said above, the `Dense` layer is applied to the last dimension), so you will need more computation. Regarding the performance, it is hard to say what would be better.

Comment: Hey @AloneTogether, I just read some documents on `a Dense layer is only applied to the last dimension of your tensor`. My current understanding is this: say each sample is a 5x2 matrix and a `Dense` layer has 8 nodes. A `Dense` layer will be applied to my matrix 5 times and in each application the `Dense` layer will be applied to a 1x2 vector?

Answer (score 0):

A mistake is in your function `make_model`.

```
def make_model(input_shape):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = layers.Dense(128, activation="ReLU")(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

You probably wanted the second line to be

```
x = layers.Dense(128, activation="ReLU")(inputs)
```

and not

```
x = layers.Dense(128, activation="ReLU")(x)
```

and unfortunately, `x` exists in scope, so it didn't throw an error.

Comment: Hey @Captain Trojan, yes you are right lol... my code is a bit more complicated than this and I forgot to rename the variable when redacting my code to make it as concise as possible...I just revised my question to fix this...